# Can I ask a question regarding a particular example?

Tags: support

I want to ask a question regarding part of the database I was studying from, I want to know did I correctly applied the first normal form into my table. I do not want to ask what first normal form is as I have all the definitions I need but I am unsure did I understand it correctly.

Can I ask such question on stackoverflow regarding a particular example, or do I need to ask it on a different forum?

Comment: It is just a theory question. No code, just a table.

Comment: @Pawel Maybe at [SE Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to meet their site policies (tables are coded BTW). Also note SE sites aren't _forums_. If you wan't to get off-site resource examples, none of the sites at SE will be right for you.

Comment: @rene Done so ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask at [SE Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to meet their site policies (tables are coded BTW).

Also note SE sites aren't forums. If you wan't to get off-site resource examples, none of the sites at SE will be right for you.